# How to read URLs containing question marks in C using microhttpd.h

Tags: c, linux, http, url-parsing

I am trying to parse the URL in C using `microhttpd library`.

```
daemon = MHD_start_daemon (MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY | MHD_USE_SSL, PORT, NULL, NULL, &answer_to_connection, NULL, MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_KEY, key_pem, MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_CERT, cert_pem, MHD_OPTION_END);
```

When I run the function `MHD_start_daemon` a call back function  `answer_to_connection` is called.

```
static int answer_to_connection(void *cls, struct MHD_Connection *connection, const char *url, const char *method, const char *version, const char *upload_data, size_t *upload_data_size, void **con_cls)
{
    printf("URL:%s\n", url);
}
```

One of the parameters of `answer_to_connection` is `const char *url`. The url variable contains the string after `https://localhost:port` example: for `http://128.19.24.123:8888/cars/ferrari` the url value will be `/cars/ferrari`

But in case of `http://128.19.24.123:8888/cars?value=ferrari` the url is printing only `cars`.

I want to print `cars?value=ferrari`. How can I do that?

There is a tutorial on microhttpd library at https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html

But I can't find any solution to this problem there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAVEAT EMPTOR: I have not used this library, this answer is based on a quick perusal of the [API](https://gnunet.org/git/libmicrohttpd.git/tree/src/include/microhttpd.h).

It looks like you can't access the whole original URL, because microhttpd parses it for you. Instead you access the individual query string values using `MHD_lookup_connection_value`, like this:

```
value = MHD_lookup_connection_value(connection, MHD_GET_ARGUMENT_KIND, "value");
```

That would return a pointer to the value of the query string argument, or null if not found.

You can also use `MHD_get_connection_values` to iterate over the query string components. In that case you would call it like this:

```
num = MHD_get_connection_values(connection, MHD_GET_ARGUMENT_KIND, iterator, cls);
```

iterator would be a callback function to receive the GET query arguments, one by one.

See also: the [Handling requests](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/html_node/microhttpd_002drequests.html) section in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

use MHD_get_connection_values to call your function, once for every name=value pair.   Lets dumb it down into an example. First you have the URL, but not the parms. So, lets show how to get the name=value pairs.   So, lets show this with an example.    call via curl, with [bla.bla.bla?name1=value1&name2=value2] .  Now, in your Answer_To_Connection(...), say we want to build a string, that looks like [name1=value1,name2=value2\0].  we call  MHD_get_connection_values (ConnectionPtr, MHD_GET_ARGUMENT_KIND, &OurFunctionToCallForEach, bufferptr);    In OurFunctionToCallForEach( void *bufferptr, MHD_VAlueKind k, const char *key, const char *value), we sprintf(strchr(bufferptr,'\0'), "%s=%s,", name, value);    Anyway, it's a crude example, which will exercise any static code analysis, but does show the procedure.  We make one call to MHD, MHD calls our function once for every name/value pair, and gives us the pointer we gave MHD.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).